# Clearing content of multiple types of controls in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

In a WPF project, I have a grid that contains other grids, labels, borders, textboxes, listboxes, what have you.

The children also contain children and so on.

How do I clear the contents of all of the textboxes and listboxes, and other controls that are editable from the original Grid and all of its children?

Comment: Your question is too broad. If you're using WPF correctly, you simply go through your view model data structures and clear all the values in them, or possibly easier (depending on your view model implementation) just discard the current view model(s) and create a whole new one. If you're not using WPF correctly, things may be much harder, but you need to try _something_ and then ask a question if and when you have a _specific_ problem you want to ask about.

Answer (score 0):

**myGrid.Children.Clear();**   // will remove all child controls nested in the grid.